# Use Google Chromium in osx

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, chromium

I have to display my Webpage in a Mac App. 
In de .NET version using chromium is really simple.

So i downloaded the chromium kit and the sample Apps are working, but i am not able to import and use the chromium in my project.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=6&sid=8989bdddbfba4fc7b2560a3b53934c27

Maybe you are able to find information there :)

Comment: thank you man! That help me a lot.